# Data duplicate when insert the data using laravel sync method?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, synchronization

I have used `laravel sync` mthod for `belongsToMany` relationship. After calling this method, sometimes duplicate data is inserted to the pivot table.

This the `code` I have used.

```
{

    $selectedScreenCategories = $this->screenCategorySiteFieldsModel->addSameKeyForElementsInArray($screenCategoryIds,'screen_category_id');
    $siteField->screenCategories()->sync($selectedScreenCategories);

}
```

This is the `migration` which is used to create `pivot` table.

```
{
    {
    public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('site_field_screen_categories',function (Blueprint $table){
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->unsignedInteger('screen_category_site_field_id')->nullable(false);
                $table->unsignedInteger('screen_category_id')->nullable(false);                
                $table->foreign('screen_category_site_field_id','screen_category_site_field_id')->references('id')->on('screen_category_site_fields');                            
                $table->foreign('screen_category_id')->references('id')->on('screen_categories');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `belongsToMany` relationship.

```
function screenCategories(){
    return  $this->belongsToMany('App\ScreenCategory','site_field_screen_categories','screen_category_site_field_id','screen_category_id');
}
```

This is the `pivot` table `before` calling the `sync` method.

[image]
This is the `sync` array for `$selectedScreenCategories`.

```
[
    0 => ["screen_category_id" => 6]
    1 => ["screen_category_id" => 3]
    2 => ["screen_category_id" => 5]
]
```

This is the `pivot` table `after` calling `sync` method.

[image]

I spent several hours. Still could not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution.**
Just change the `integer keys` in to `string keys` of the array `$selectedScreenCategories` which is passed in to `sync` function like below.

Change

```
[
    0 => ["screen_category_id" => 6]
    1 => ["screen_category_id" => 3]
    2 => ["screen_category_id" => 5]
]
```

Into

```
[
    "Gfdsj" => ["screen_category_id" => 6]
    "pQrst" => ["screen_category_id" => 3]
    "uvWzy" => ["screen_category_id" => 5]
]
```

You can use `str_random(5)` php function to make random strings like `"Gfdsj"`. This will fix your issue.

**Reason for the issue.**
Check the already existing record of the `pivot` table before run the `sync` function.
That record for `screen_category_id = 1`.

Then check the array `$selectedScreenCategories` which is passed to `sync` function. See the image below.

[image]

When we pass this array to `sync` function, because there is a record for `screen_category_id = 1` already, above highlighted record is the reason to getting updated the already existing record as `screen_category_id = 3`. Now we have 2 records for `screen_category_id = 3`. 
Hope you will understand.

Comment: Works like magic bro

Comment: the problem with this solution is this completely disable sync method and previous data doesn't delete anymore

Comment: Wouldn't the correct solution be, to pass values of `screen_category_id` as indexed array and use relation method to define you column name ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the combination to be unique in your pivot table, remove the `id` from pivot table. In order to stop duplicate record you need to make unique key. In your current table `id` is the primary key and incremental.

You can remove the `id` and create composite primary key like

```
$table->primary(['screen_category_site_field_id', 'screen_category_id']);
```

Above will really enforce unique data.

Alternative is you can keep the table as it is and detach the data first and sync again.

Comment: I had a similar problem but I don't have an ID field on the PIVOT table, I solved it quickly with the approach of detaching all and attach again, is there a better solution?